# How do I copy the first layer of a folder structure in python?

Tags: python, directory, copy

Consider following folder structure

```
├─a
│  ├─a1
│  ├─a2
|      ├─a2_1
│      ├─a2_2
│  └─a3
│      ├─a3_1
│      ├─a3_2
│      └─a3_3
```

Is there any way to copy the folders a1, a2, a3 without any subfolders or files into a folder b so it would look like this:

```
├─b
│  ├─a1
│  ├─a2
|  └─a3
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you have any additional question?

Comment: @Matthias I guess the one in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to copy subdirectories or files, you aren't really performing any copy at all. All you need to do is to create directories with same names as in the input folder.

```
import os

adir = 'a'
bdir = 'b'

for fn in os.listdir(adir):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(adir, fn)):
      os.mkdir(os.path.join(bdir, fn))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
import os

for name in os.listdir("<PATH_TO_A>"):
    if os.path.isdir("<PATH_TO_A>" + name):
        os.mkdir("<PATH_TO_B>" + name)
```

Comment: It would also create directories with names same as all the files contained in `a`.

Comment: Yes, just checked it, but you were quicker! (Corrected it)